# Custom pagination - arrows not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a strange problem where the arrows generated for next & previous pages don't work. I just can't seem to fix it. The html seems to be fine and numbers work, but when clicked on nothing happens: http://sketchbookmagazine.com/category/fashion/

Pagination code:

```
function pagination($prev = '«', $next = '»') {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current,
        'prev_text' => __($prev),
        'next_text' => __($next),
        'type' => 'plain'
);
    if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

    if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
};
```

html:

```
<div class="pagination"><?php pagination('«','»'); ?></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are two scripts which are not loading, not sure if that is a cause?

http://sketchbookmagazine.com/category/fashion/page/2/js/plugins.js
http://sketchbookmagazine.com/category/fashion/page/2/js/script.js

Comment: I have taken these out as just planning to move code here (they are empty) - but unfortunately it didn't impact on it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this construct:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
```

Try changing that to:

```
$current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. Have modified the code but still no luck. It's weird because the <a> tags seem to be correct, yet don't work. Any ideas?